# Can I use all features of java time library with Android Sdk<=26

Tags: java, android, kotlin, java-time

The java time library has features in DateTimeFormatter, LocalTime library etc that android studio pointed out only has support in sdk version >= 26. I currently need it in my app. So, do I need to increase my minSdkVersion to 26(which will not support a lot of devices), or implement my own methods. Android puts the option of adding the requires api notation, will this mean earlier sdk versions will not have access to that capability?

It is pretty surprising though that a decent time library only as support for sdk version 26. It is worth noting that the project is written in kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade minSdkVersion to 26. As current version is 30 so 26 is very low as compare to this. Also you no need to worry about that it is not supported by most devices. In reality most of the devices are targeted by this version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Really helps give perspective

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library which is a port of `java.time.*` for older Android versions, but with a different package name. The drawback is that it can perform worse, increases code size and method number, and likely won't get updated.
2. A considerable portion of `java.time.*` should be available independent of the minimum API version, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table.
3. You can see market share of different versions at https://gs.statcounter.com/android-version-market-share/mobile/worldwide/, SDK 26 corresponds to 8.0 (Oreo). So ~87% of Android devices worldwide has this version or greater, but it may depend on your target audience.